# Krajee's File Input plugin - how to catch invalid file extension and show error message

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I'm using Krajee the Bootstrap File Input plugin to perform an upload via form submit POST call.

I want to restrict filesize to 2 MB and file types to "doc" or "docx". Using multiple-form-data POST submit.

My code is as follow:

```
<p>
<input type="file" name="file1" id="idfile" class="file" 
          data-show-preview="false" data-show-remove="false" data-show-upload="false"/>
</p>

$("#id_file").fileinput({
maxFileSize: 2000,
allowedFileExtensions: ['doc', 'docx']
});
    $('#id_file').on('fileerror', function(event, data) {
    alert("Invalid file type");    
});
```

I believe fileerror event should be triggered when uploaded file type is no doc or docx. However, "fileerror" event is not triggered.

I also want to show default error message "msgInvalidFileType" which is raised when this error is triggered. But can not find out how to get this done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Suraj

Comment: Can somebody help with this?

Comment: Facing same issue with images @Suraj

Comment: Any solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the it's just a silly mistake.

Your input id is "idfile" and inside javascript you're refering as $("#id_file") and both should be equal.

BTW i do some tests and i noticed that fileerror event is called only if you not set the uploadUrl option.

Head to http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#error-events for more information